# how to check if a frame was exited by the user clicking the close button?

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

how to can I check if a frame was exited by the user clicking the close button. I need to know because I have two wx.frames, a child and parent. When the parent frame is closed the how do I close the child frame? 
I'm using wxpython

Comment: Easy thing.. you can do is write a function to handle the close button and in that function, you can just check if there're any child frames to get closed. Yes, if there're .. close'em. Then, you can terminate the parent frame as well. As simple as that.. Regarding the code, tell me if you have a problem with the implementation of the above idea

Comment: @user673919 thanks, what is the close button called? Its usuallly wx.- Something

Comment: Writing the full answer.. Wait a sec!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say the main Parent frame be parent.

```
class parent(wx.Frame):
      def __init__(self, parent):
            ## Ur GUI's code ##

            self.Bind( wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.ParentFrameOnClose )
      def ParentFrameOnClose(self, event):
            self.DestroyChildren()  ## Destroy the children first
            self.Destroy()    ## Destroy the parent then.
```